# Django, I want to take an input from a form and contents of the template should be according to the input

Tags: django, django-templates

**models.py**

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateField('created_date')
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    abc = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pqr = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ghi = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Then I take a user input

**input.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="search/" style="margin-left:5em;">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="radio" name="account" value="price"> price<br>
  <input type="radio" name="account" value="abc"> abc<br>
  <input type="radio" name="account" value="pqr"> pqr<br>
  <input type="radio" name="account" value="ghi"> ghi<br>
</form>
```

**views. py**

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_id = request.POST.get("account", None)
        selected_transactions = Transaction.objects.exclude(search_id=0)
        return render(request, 'stats/account_details.html', {'selected_transactions': selected_transactions,
                                                              'search_id': search_id})
    else:
        return render(request, 'stats/index.html')
```

I have to display contents based on user input.

**account_details.html**

```
<table>
        <tr>
        <th>Transaction date</th>
        <th>{{ search_id }}</th>
      </tr>
    {% for transaction in selected_transactions %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ transaction.created_date }}</td>
        <td>{{ transaction.{{ search_id }} }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}

</table>
```

I have two issues here.

1.`Transaction.objects.exclude(search_id=0)` doesn't work. It does not take the value of variable search_id. How do I exclude dynamically those transactions where user input attribute=0?

2.`{{ transaction.{{ search_id }} }}` in account_details.html doesn't work as it is a syntax error. I need to display data varying on user input. How do I use two variables inside a single tag in my template?

I get that I can resolve both using if else statements, but I have a large no. of attributes. So, is there a shorter way to do it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You dont have a field `search_id` for your model Transaction, then how can it work??

Comment: e.g.. if I select 'abc' in my form, won't variable search_id be assigned to 'abc' by search_id = request.POST.get("account", None) in views.py?

Comment: Yes, but how does this work, `Transaction.objects.exclude(search_id=0)`??
manager methods only takes the field names as keyword arguments... Please look into querysets and query methods in django!

Comment: I understand. Is there a way for this keyword argument to be dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

Issue 1: You are trying to use an attribute in a query set filter which is not present in your model. You might want to use any of your attributes of your model like price or any other attribute.

Issue 2: Code below:

```
<td>{{ transaction.created_date }}</td>
<td>{{ transaction.{{ search_id }} }}</td>
```

is not correct for various reasons. First thing that you are trying to access created_date attribute which is not present in your queryset attribute. Either you have to remove this attribute or add it into your model. Your second line is incorrect because its a syntax error. Below one might be helpful to you and its syntactically correct.

```
<td> {{ search_id }} </td>
```

Edit: You can put if else to compare which search_id is selected by the user and based on that corresponding data can be displayed.

```
{% if search_id == "abc" %}
    {{ transaction.abc }}
{% elif search_id == "pqr" %}
    {{ transaction.pqr }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: <td> {{ search_id }} </td> doesn't solve the purpose. User may select 'abc' or 'pqr' in my case and I need to display transaction.abc or transaction.pqr respectively.

Comment: If so then put an if else. Do you want update to the answer for if else

Comment: Yes, please. That would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you Arpit for this. Isn't there a shorter method for this, in case I have a large no. of attributes?

Comment: If you have large number of attributes than i would suggest don't rely on templates, use the same logic in view with loops and send the appropriate data to template in context